# Executable says "line 1: ELF: not found" when starts

Tags: c, linux, cmake, elf, openwrt

I try to build a simple **hello, world** `ELF` for my router `Xiaomi Router 3g` with `cmake`. It runs

```
Linux OpenWrt 4.14.95 #0 SMP Wed Jan 30 12:21:02 2019 mips GNU/Linux
```

I use [the sdk for ramips platform (my router's platform)](https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/targets/ramips/mt7621/openwrt-sdk-ramips-mt7621_gcc-7.4.0_musl.Linux-x86_64.tar.xz).

The idea is to use `$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)` as a directory to perform an external build (which is usually done via `mkdir build ; cd build ; cmake ..`)

The build finishes successfully and when I install it on my router and start it, it fails with:

```sh
root@OpenWrt:~# chw
/usr/bin/chw: line 1: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/chw: line 2: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

When I build the `ELF` without `cmake` (

1. comment out the line `include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/cmake.mk`,
2. uncomment the  `$(CP) ...` line in the `define Build/Prepare` section
3. eliminate the `define Build/Compile` section

), it works just fine: it prints **Hello, World!**.

Log file is [here](https://gist.github.com/neshkeev/28f3828688fe354e7358bc9b1fbbe9a5), 
`.config` file is [here](https://gist.github.com/neshkeev/02da79c8d39226d233f5d05dc13833a0)

**The source code is available** [here](https://github.com/neshkeev/openwrt-cmake-demo)

Here is the source code:

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (chw)

add_executable(chw main.c)

install(TARGETS chw DESTINATION /usr/bin)
```

`Makefile`:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=chw
PKG_VERSION:=0.1
PKG_RELEASE:=1

PKG_MAINTAINER:=John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
PKG_LICENSE:=CC0-1.0

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/cmake.mk

define Package/chw
    SECTION:=utils
    CATEGORY:=Utilities
    TITLE:=Hello world application
    URL:=https://www.example.com
endef

define Package/chw/description
    hello world application
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    # $(CP) ./src/{main.c,Makefile} $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef

define Build/Configure
    cmake -B $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) -S ./src
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(call Build/Compile/Default,-C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR))
endef

define Package/chw/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/chw $(1)/usr/bin/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,chw))
```

Comment: The error suggests that your ELF binary is being executed as a shell script.  I don't immediately see why that is, however.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Yeah, that is weird, I thought about it and tried to `cat` the ELF, but it appeared to be a binary file.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect an ELF file to be binary. If a UNIX-like OS doesn't know how to execute an ELF file directly, or doesn't recognize your file as ELF, it will try to feed it to `/bin/sh`. The shell doesn't necessarily reject binary files, but it's likely to choke on them because of bad syntax. What does `file chw` tell you? (Run that command on your host system if the target doesn't have a `file` command.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, thank you for your comment, I tried to run the app on my host computer and it works, apparently the `sdk` builds `ELF` for my host system and not for my router. I need to figure out how to use `cmake` for building `ELF` for my router. Feel free to leave your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently your target system either doesn't support executing ELF files, or doesn't recognize your file as an ELF file.

When you execute a file on a UNIX-like system, it will be executed directly if the kernel recognizes it as an executable format. If not, if there's no `#!` line at the top, it will try to execute it as a shell script using `/bin/sh`. It's a binary file, but there's no really firm distinction between binary and text files.

The shell apparently tried to interpret the beginning of the file (which includes the characters `ELF`) as a command, and wasn't able to find that command in `$PATH`.

You'll need to find a way to generate an executable file that your target system will recognize and accept. (I don't know how to do that.)

Comment: Saved me while implementing a docker image for python!

Answer (score 15):

In addition to other answers here, there might be simple cause for `"line 1: ELF: not found, line 2: syntax error: unexpected "(""`:

You are running a **64-bit** program on a **32-bit** machine. Try changing your compiling config.

Comment: this is exactly what I encountered with my .net core program on debian. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember to change the file property to make it executable?

```
chmod +x filename
```

I know I often forget this step when I download something (usually an installation binary).
Just a thought!

Comment: That wouldn't cause that particular error message.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using WSL 1.  You need to switch to WSL 2 to run ELF

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that the ELF is not for the correct architecture (e.g. trying to execute an X86_64 ELF on an ARM system).